# Finishing a ncurses application and letting the screen untouched

Tags: ncurses, curses

When we end a ncurses application it (usually) restores the last terminal screen (at least in xterm emulators, it does). How to quit of a ncurses application properly (ending ncurses) and let the screen untouched?

Actually, it's a function that initiates ncurses, "paint" the screen and when it returns (ending and cleaning ncurses structures) the last screen is restored and everything that the function has wrote on the screen is lost (it disappears).

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve this problem too - for `pspg`, and I found only one stable and robust solution. After ncurses ending, I draw the content again - without ncurses, just with ANSI sequences.